# Can you have negative profit in the stalk market, or does it 'bottom out' at zero?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

The stalk market badge in New Leaf has a badge for making a profit selling turnips. The bronze requires a total cumulative profit of 500,000 bells. I'm interested to know how this is calculated - if you keep making a loss every week, do you end up with a massive negative overall profit (which you'd have to claw back before you could even begin working back towards the badge), or does it bottom out at zero?

For example, let's say we spend 100,000 bells on turnips one week, and only sell them for 50,000. Is my total profit now -50,000 or zero?

Comment: +1 That's a great question.  How would someone find this info though?  That's not something that we can ever see in-game, is it?

Comment: Actually, you can calculate it if you know your present total spend and sell. Eg, let's say I know I've lost millions of bells on the stalk market. I then take care to earn exactly 500,000 (or more) bells in the following weeks. If Phineas now hands me the badge, then I know the system bottoms out at zero. If he doesn't, then I know it goes into the negative.

Answer (score 2):

I used to do a lot of Stalk Market trading and there were other people who were doing it and and we spent a lot of time calculating profits and costs etc.

Basically losing money doesn't affect anything. Whenever you buy and then sell for higher, that profit goes towards the achievement. If you ever incur a loss that doesn't affect your your profit. If you made a profit of 50 then you lost 500 and the you made a profit of 100 the game will have it as you having made a profit of 150.